# Applying Windows 10 Touch Screen Changes

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

I have a script that auto-maps/validates monitor to touchscreen settings. I am updating the registry keys in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\Digimon (like the Windows multidigimon calibration app does) with new/corrected entries when monitors occasionally come up wrong. The script works fine, however, I can't figure out how to apply the settings without logging out/back in.

I am trying to figure out if there is a service and/or process I need to restart to apply the settings. It must be possible because the multidigimon calibration app does just that. Also, it's not the "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Services"

Answer (score 2):

Restarting dwm.exe is enough. Just kill it and let Windows start it back.

Comment: Confirmed this works perfectly.